# How to create your own bitcoin mining software?

Tags: mining-software

Can we create mining software, if yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible

1. Take an editor (notepad.exe is good one)
2. Write a program
3. Compile and test it
4. Thats all. Profit!

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course.

If you are looking for a place to start, look at the mining related functions of the Bitcoin RPC (`bitcoin-cli help`) for the input data you will need for any mining application.